# HTTP Request Error in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, xmlhttprequest

I am getting a HTTP request error in Flex. Not always but sometimes. However I do see that the HTTP request was successfully sent to the backend.

I am printing the "HttpService.lastResult.Error" which has this String.

How can I get the root cause of this problem ? Apart from "HttpService.lastResult.Error" are there any other Flex Objects whose state can help me get more information as to why the Request Failed ?

Are there any Flex related debugging tools ?? 
Is there a way to print the Trace of every HTTP request that Flex makes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the FaultEvent and catch it, it has some kind of message.

In Flash builder 4 there is a Network Monitor that could really help!

Comment: Hi Keyle, Thanks for the answer. I decided to Print event.message.toString(); this has more information. What are the tools with which I can debug an Application on the Client environment ? I mean, I can't install Flex Builder 4 on the machine's where I am getting this error.

Comment: I'd say add a textfield and output all the tracing you can do to that field so when it runs on that machine you can easily inspect it.